# Deserializing complex JSON response using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am developing my web application backend using Spring. In particular, my application manages data on soccer teams and their players.

My application interacts with a third party REST API to fetch team and player data.

As for the teams, I created a `Team` entity as follows:

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "team")
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String logoUrl;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "team")
    private Set<Player> players;
}
```

The response that comes to me from the API, however, has a particular structure and contains an array of Teams in the "response" node.

Here is the structure of the response:

```json
{
   "get":"teams",
   "parameters":{
      "league":"135",
      "season":"2020"
   },
   "errors":[
      
   ],
   "results":20,
   "paging":{
      "current":1,
      "total":1
   },
   "response":[
      {
         "team":{
            "id":487,
            "name":"Lazio",
            "country":"Italy",
            "founded":1900,
            "national":false,
            "logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/487.png"
         },
         "venue":{
            "id":910,
            "name":"Stadio Olimpico",
            "address":"Viale dei Gladiatori, 2 \/ Via del Foro Italico",
            "city":"Roma",
            "capacity":68530,
            "surface":"grass",
            "image":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/venues\/910.png"
         }
      },
      {
         "team":{
            "id":488,
            "name":"Sassuolo",
            "country":"Italy",
            "founded":1922,
            "national":false,
            "logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/488.png"
         },
         "venue":{
            "id":935,
            "name":"MAPEI Stadium - Citt\u00e0 del Tricolore",
            "address":"Piazza Azzuri d&apos;Italia, 1",
            "city":"Reggio nell&apos;Emilia",
            "capacity":23717,
            "surface":"grass",
            "image":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/venues\/935.png"
         }
      },
      ... // Other team objects
   ]
}
```

How can I parse the answer to get a `List<Team>` using the Jackson library?

Comment: You can implement a custom deserializer as explained here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create classes for Jackson that match result structure then convert instances of those classes to your `Team` class. Using same class for JPA entity and for Jackson deserialization is a bad idea.

There are online services that allow generating classes like this. For example this one https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo generated classes like this:

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
/* ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class); */
public class Parameters{
    public String league;
    public String season;
}

public class Paging{
    public int current;
    public int total;
}

public class Team{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String country;
    public int founded;
    public boolean national;
    public String logo;
}

public class Venue{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public int capacity;
    public String surface;
    public String image;
}

public class Response{
    public Team team;
    public Venue venue;
}

public class Root{
    public String get;
    public Parameters parameters;
    public List<Object> errors;
    public int results;
    public Paging paging;
    public List<Response> response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Sankozi! Since in my project I already have an `entity` package with the`Team` class I mentioned above, all the autogenerated classes (including `Team`) from the website you posted in which package should they be put?

Comment: @MarcoGelli I would rename Team class so names do not clash (Team from code for Jackson). Class names will not be used in deserializing in this case. I would put those classes in package with name related to the API you are using so maybe `<project root package>.apisports`?

Answer (score 1):

As @Sankozi said you can modelize your java pojos for json deserialization.
Then use an ObjectMapper for deserialization like :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                 
CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
  .constructCollectionType(List.class, Response.class);                 
List<Response> asList = mapper.readValue(jsonArray, javaType);                 
List<Team> teams = asList.stream()     
  .flatMap(response -> response.getTeam())                         
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```